# How to write a customised Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have dozens of functions with `try` `catch` block to handle and log any error occurred.

```
 function add(a, b) {
            try {
                return a + b;
            } catch (error) {
                log.error(error.message + ' in add');
            }
        }
```

As this try catch statements have same kind of code for each function mentioning error message and the function name in each log, I want some way to avoid writing `try` `catch` for each function and want it to be added automatically. My `function` should be like below one but should work like above one.

```
 function add(a, b) {
           return a + b;
        }
```

How could it be possible?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `try/catch` in every function. That's what test frameworks are for. Or Typescript if you want to catch type errors in your IDE.

Comment: @Andy I am using native javascript, no frameworks. Thanks

Comment: Ok, test _libraries_. They run in parallel to your code in your build process so that you don't have to add `try/catch` to every function. You can run your tests and they'll tell you if your function is working properly.

Comment: Actually I am saving log to server and I must have to save it for monitoring and history management.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap your functions up using [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

For logging, you can try using [`Function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), but for meaningful information this rules out arrow functions and otherwise anonymous functions. This could be solved by explicitly passing a name string to the `wrap` function, but...

There is of course no guarantee the returned function is used via an identifier related to the original name (`whatever` vs `anError` below).

```js
const wrap = func => (...args) => {
    try {
        return func.apply(this, args);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`${e} in ${func.name}`);
    }
};

const add = wrap((a, b) => a + b);
const fail = wrap(t => {
    if (t)
        throw new Error('foo');
});
const whatever = wrap(function anError () {
    throw 'an error';
});

console.log(add(1, 2));
fail(false);
fail(true);
whatever();
```

Combined output:

```
3
Error: foo in
an error in anError
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need method name in log to track, as you can see in question.

Answer (score 1):

can you try with callback...

```
function add(a, b){
    return a + b;
}

function substract(a, b){
    return a - b;
}

function calc(a){
    try{
        const f = Array.prototype.shift.apply(arguments);
        return f(...arguments);
    }catch(e){
        console.log(e.stack);
    }
}

calc(substract, 1, 2);
```